# print a string directly to printer

Tags: delphi, printing, delphi-xe6

i need to print a string directly into the printer
i found this code by searching

```
uses WinSpool, Printers

type
  TDoc_Info_1 = record
    pDocName: pChar;
    pOutputFile: pChar;
    pDataType: pChar;
  end;


procedure PrintSimpleText(sPrinter, sText: String);
var
  sTitle: String;
  hPrinter: THandle;
  PrnDocInfo: TDoc_Info_1;
  lst: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
  n: Cardinal;
  sTextLine: String;
  bFound: Boolean;
begin
  lst := TStringList.Create;
  try
    lst.Text := sText; //with CRLF
    //new doc
    sTitle := 'Raw print';
    ZeroMemory(@PrnDocInfo, SizeOf(TDoc_Info_1));
    PrnDocInfo.pDocName := PChar(sTitle);
    PrnDocInfo.pDataType := 'RAW';
    //find printer (if is installed in windows)
    bFound := False;
    for i:=1 to Printer.Printers.Count do
    begin
      if Pos(sPrinter, Printer.Printers.Strings[i-1])>0 then
      begin
        bFound := True;
        sPrinter := Printer.Printers.Strings[i-1];
        Printer.PrinterIndex := i-1; //set printer
        Break;
      end;
    end;

    if bFound then
    begin
      // open the printer
      if OpenPrinter(PChar(sPrinter), hPrinter, nil) then
      begin
        //start
        StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, @PrnDocInfo);
        if StartPagePrinter(hPrinter) then
        begin
          //print by line
          for i := 1 to lst.Count do
          begin
            sTextLine := lst.Strings[i-1];
            if not WritePrinter(hPrinter, PChar(sTextLine), Length(sTextLine), n) then
              Break;
          end;
          //end of page
          EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
          //end
          EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
        end;
        ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    lst.Free;
  end;
end;
```

and this run like this :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PrintSimpleText('pdfFactory Pro', 'Tis is a'#13#10'text');
  showmessage('aaaa');
end;
```

1)
but by clicking `Button1` it just show a message!!!
is it required to send a custom header with the string for print?
or what is the problem here?

2)
also if you think this is not a good way tell me a better solution! i need to submit a string like this to the printer

```
------------------------------------------------------
      your card number is 1111 1111 1111 1111
           your name is mr xxxx xxxxxxx
        your nationality code is 9999999999
------------------------------------------------------
              your password is : 555555
-----------------------------------------------------
```

at first i tried to save string into a text file and send it to pronter but printer printed the file name at the top of the file

then i tried to create a bitmap image and send it to the machine 
but the printer is a dot matrix and don't understand the image!!

UPDATE:

this code work perfectly on my pc
i think printer is detected and working fine.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
ShellExecute(Handle, 'print', PChar(OpenDialog1.FileName), nil, nil, SW_HIDE) ;
end;
```

Comment: Read the documentation for your printer and do what it says. You can't really just spew text at a printer and hope that it can read your mind.

Comment: The code you present was written for AnsiString. In XE6 standard string type is unicode. Change pChar to pAnsiChar and String to AnsiString.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `pdfFactory Pro` a virtual universal printer to print string to a pdf file!! aslo my post have two question :) thank you

Comment: Your program doesn't notify the user if the `OpenPrinter` or `WritePrinter` fails. You should add notifications and see if either of those fails.

Comment: @LURD your changed dont helped.

Comment: Those changes must be there anyway. Have you debugged the code. Is the printer detected for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this can do your job too

```
  Printer.BeginDoc;
  Printer.Canvas.TextOut(0,0,'Place any text here');
  Printer.EndDoc;
```

also with canvas you can edit styling too

```
   Printer.Canvas.Font.size:=18;
   Printer.Canvas.Font.style := [fsbold];
```

Answer (score 5):

Example how to write some text directly to the default printer like to the text file.

```
uses ..., Printers;

...

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  lst: TextFile;
begin
  AssignPrn(lst);
  Rewrite(lst);
  try
    Writeln(lst, '      your card number is 1111 1111 1111 1111');
    Writeln(lst, '           your name is mr xxxx xxxxxxx');
    Writeln(lst, '        your nationality code is 9999999999');
    Writeln(lst, '------------------------------------------------------');
  finally
    CloseFile(lst);
  end;
end;
```

Especially useful with matrix printers.

Answer (score 4):

If the printer is available over the network:

```
procedure Print(const AText: string);
var
  F: TStreamWriter;
begin
  F := TStreamWriter.Create('\\printserver\printername', False, TEncoding.Default);
  try
    F.Write(AText);
  finally
    F.Free;
  end;
end;
```

(Tested with Delphi 2009)

Answer (score 1):

When need send commands directly to printer can use the class "Printer".
To writing one string use the code:

```
procedure TForm1.btTextoNormalClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  ComandoAnsiString := 'Example text';

  if not OpenPrinter(PChar(driverName), HandleImp, nil) then 
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Erro: Impressora não encontrada')

  else
  begin

  Documento.pDocName := PChar('Minha impressão');
  Documento.pOutputFile := nil;
  Documento.pDataType := 'RAW';


  StartDocPrinter(HandleImp, 1, @Documento);

  StartPagePrinter(HandleImp);


  WritePrinter(HandleImp, PAnsiChar(ComandoAnsiString), Length(ComandoAnsiString), CaracteresImpressos);

  EndPagePrinter(HandleImp);
  EndDocPrinter(HandleImp);
  ClosePrinter(HandleImp);


  end;

end;
```

To get the driverName use the code in a ComboBox:

```
cbbDriver.Items := Printer.Printers;
```