# Connection Delphi Printer

Tags: delphi, printing, winsock

I need to connect my Delphi software to a SmartDate x40 printer, I've tried using winslock. I'm very new at Delphi and I'm unable to make it work, I'd highly appreciate any tips or little help any of you kind guys could make.

I've seen a few posts about using Winslock with Delphi, tho all of them use a client-server connection in whish is the client the one making the connection, I'd need being the server initiating the communication to the SmartDate machine being able to send a few ASCII orders.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Clients initiate the connection. That's not up for debate. Stack Overflow is not a forum. You don't ask for hints. You must ask specific detailed questions. Please read the site's help topics.

Comment: [If the printer is available over the network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371291/print-a-string-direclty-to-printer/25376788#25376788)

Comment: Okay, I apologize for the mistake. I'll keep trying. Thank you for your help David.

Comment: @MrBadProgrammer Is the printer connected to the network or attached to the computer via USB?

Comment: Network, I know IP and Port. What I need is some way of just send a string of characters to the printer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you misunderstand the terms client and server. The printer is the server (it serves the client application'. Your application is the client (it asks the printer to do something.) That is why the examples are as they are. Your application could be a server for something else, but it is still a client of the printer.